# Cannot bring from the suggestion list in a modal

Tags: javascript, html, css, angular, primeng

I use `PrimeNG` [AutoComplete](https://www.primefaces.org/primeng/#/autocomplete) inside `PrimeNG` [Dialog](https://www.primefaces.org/primeng/#/dialog) and I list elements below the `AutoComplete` in this dialog.

I want to do:

1. The `max-height` of the `modal dialog` is 300, if the added elements' total height is bigger than it then modal's `scrollbar` should be visible.
2. When there is no element in the list, the `AutoComplete's` suggestion list should be visible over the dialog.

But when I set the `overflow` property of the modal or not, the `AutoComplete` suggestion list is displayed inside the modal. Is it possible to make 2 elements as shown below? I also display `scrollbar` when the total elements in the modal are 10. Any idea?

Here is CSS style:

```
body .ui-dialog {
    overflow-y: auto !important;
    max-height: 300px;
}

body.ui-autocomplete-panel{
    position: relative;
    z-index: 9998!important;
}
```

Comment: You can set the property `appendTo="body"` on your autocomplete component ([documentation](https://www.primefaces.org/primeng/#/autocomplete)).

Comment: please share code sample to replicate your issue in stackblitz or codesandbox

Answer (score 0):

add `appendTo="body"` worked to me